# jQuery event target element attribute retrieval

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, this, target

I'm having some trouble pulling attributes from an event target element.

I am using php to access a mysql database. From the query I pull out some image file names and their respective id's. I then display these images in a table with the following line:

```
print '<td><img id="img_' . $row['paint_id'] . '" class="thumb_target" src="img/paint/thumb/' . $row['paint_thumb'] .'"></td>';
```

As you can see, this line gives each image the id 'img_xx' where xx is the images numeric id in the sql database. I also give each image the class 'thumb_target'. In document ready I set a .click event for the thumb_target elements. This makes an AJAX call which should pass the img_xx id as data. I got this to work in chrome using

```
data: 'imgID=' + event.target.id
```

However, several hours later I decided to check something else in firefox and found that it doesn't work for all browsers. Using jQuery's method:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

I can't get id to be anything but undefined. **Am I targeting a different element than the element I think I am?**

Here's the pertinent javascript:

```
function runClick() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'overlay.php',
    //~ data: 'imgID=' + event.target.id,
    //~ data: ({ imgID: id }),
    data: 'imgID=' + id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        processJSON(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Failed to perform AJAX call! textStatus: (" + textStatus +
              ") and errorThrown: (" + errorThrown + ")");
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.thumb_target').click( function() {
    runClick();
  });

  $('#overlay').hide();
});
```

Here's a link to the test page: http://www.carlthomasedwards.com/painting2.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runClick` is executed in global scope, so `this` refers to the global object(`window`).

Use that instead:

```
$('.thumb_target').click( function(event) {
    runClick.apply(this);
  });
```

or even more simple:

```
$('.thumb_target').click( runClick);
```

Comment: This is still giving me undefined...     $('.thumb_target').click( function(event) {
        runClick().apply(this);
      });

Comment: without the brackets, see above(or use the other variant)

Comment: Huh, the second one fixes it. I was wondering if I hadn't passed the event properly. I'm thinking Rafi's approach may be the correct way to pass it then since the first method doesn't work.

Comment: the first method will also work, it has to be `runClick.apply` not `runClick().apply`

Comment: Ah, my mistake, you are correct they both work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

When the browser executes `runClick`, the `this` context isn't preserved. If you pause in the [Chrome debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), you can see that `this` is actually `Window` when `runClick` is called.

The way to bypass the problem is to pass the element into `runClick`:

```
function runClick(elem) {
  alert($(elem).attr('id'));
  ...
}
```

and

```
$('.thumb_target').click( function() {
  runClick(this);
});
```

Comment: The other answer is better :(

Comment: This works as well though. I am going to accept the other answer, but I tested yours and it does work, so upvoted :).